# Closing a window completely in Visual Studio, terminating the VS-debugger as well

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to close my window after creating it and everything works well except one tiny detail: the debugger in the Visual Studio is still open. This means that there's still something not closed entirely I guess (a COM object?).

This is part of the code within my WinMain():

```
MSG msg;

while (TRUE)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
    }
    else
    {
        // RUN GAME CODE
        // ...
    }
}

return msg.wParam;
} // end of WinMain()
```

I placed a breakpoint just within the if and on running, I find that the if condition never resolves to true even when I close my window. What should I be doing to ensure that the window closes completely.

Below is my WinProc();

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You should use a `while` loop to drain all messages in between game updates. Otherwise message will start to pile up, and it'll take some time to have them processed.

Comment: @IInspectable Wouldnt that also drain the quit message itself? I'll give it a try tho... thanks for the advise mate.

Comment: It would, eventually, once all messages are serviced, that lead to the `WM_DESTROY` handler invoking `PostQuitMessage`. That can take some time when dispatching a single message in between game updates. Have you set a breakpoint on the `PostQuitMessage` call to see when/if it gets hit?

Comment: The WM_QUIT message is not associated with a specific window.  The second argument of PeekMessage() must be NULL.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks that worked swell!

Comment: @IInspectable so it wasnt reaching that point initially but applying Hans' advise above it was fixed. Seems the quit message is not part of the window somehow. Makes sense if we are taking window class with multiple window handles into account i guess.

Comment: Correct, `WM_QUIT` is a thread message. This should be obvious from the `PostQuitMessage()` signature, because there is no parameter that references a window (in contrast to, say, `PostMessage`). Removing the `hWnd` filter from the `PeekMessage`-call solves the issue, as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44759296/1889329) by Hans Passant. Not sure, why he decided to delete it. I voted to undelete it.